# onDisplayPreferenceDialog() with android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android

I try to display an own dialog in my android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen - I created a layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.github.pinball83.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
        android:id="@+id/licenseText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:mask="8 (***) *** **-**"
        app:notMaskedSymbol="*"

        app:maskIconColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in my settings preference xml I did

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.codevscolor.materialpreference.widget.MaterialPreferenceCategory android:title="Allgemeines">



        <com.sgi.smartcontrust.EditTextDialogPreference
            android:key="key4"
            android:title="Time Preference"
            android:summary="Time Summary"
            android:defaultValue="90"
              />


    </com.codevscolor.materialpreference.widget.MaterialPreferenceCategory>



</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

My appropriate class is

```
public class EditTextDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {
    public EditTextDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_dialog_license);
        setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
        setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);

        setDialogIcon(null);
    }
}
```

but I am getting the error

> Tried to display dialog for unknown preference type.
>
> Did you forget to override onDisplayPreferenceDialog()?

What am I doing wrong. Could anybody help me?